# Symfony redirect user BEFORE logout event

Tags: php, symfony, saml-2.0, symfony-3.4

I have a Symfony 3.4 project (with FosUser if this helps) with multiple login types (local,Oauth2,ldap) that all logouts (in the end) are handled from a local user via the default logout method.

In SAML protocol however the logout needs to take place with redirect to Idp (Identity provider, here the Azure AD) take the success response and logout the user local.

In my online search only this documentation for 5.1 symfony (and not for 3.4) https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-logout-customization explains how is possible to trigger some code before logout event happen and not after (like a logout listener or subscriber does).

How is possible for a 3.4 Symfony project to check if the login type of a user is saml or not BEFORE the logout event happens? If it is saml, can I redirect him to Idp (and back to custom route) and continue the process?

Comment: In 3.4 (and probably later too) every firewall gets initialized with a FirewallMap containing lots of listeners. One of those is a [`LogoutListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.php) that handles the logout by default.
One way would be to add your own logout listener with higher priority and when setting a response on the event you can prevent later listeners from acting, effectively overriding the default LogoutListener. Otherwise you could probably also *replace* the logoutlistener (or decorate)

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi for your answer. Logout Listener is my first thought too. And i have use it to write to my Action Log Entity. As i say in my question listeners only runs AFTER the event has ended not before as i require for SAML logout and you can't redirect in a listener because that will trigger a error.

Comment: have you even taken a look at the logout listener i linked? because that one *causes* the logout. it handles a different event, and on that kind of event you can set the response (for example a redirect response) which stops the event propagation. that particular logout listener actually does exactly that. enjoy.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer @Jakumi , yes it seems that this class does exactly what i needed . I try to user that listener all day but i can't figure out how to use it. Can you give me a hint how to proceed with what? I need to extend this class, need to make a new service or over wright this service somehow? How to trigger my custom logic before finish the login request? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: listeners all have a priority. your listener should come before the logout listener and should be similar in that it listens to the same event, checks whether the user requests the same logout path (as the logoutlistener does), somehow finds out how the user logged in (maybe a session cookie or some value in db?) and only then sets the redirect response for your external logout. SO isn't your personal coder, so what you should do is attempt this on your own, which apparently you have tried, then post your code, describe what doesn't work (probably in a new question) and move on from there.

Comment: Thanks again @Jakumi . You are right and it works exactly as you suggest. The logout listener has priority 7 so i create a listener with priority above that and (if it is external user) i return a new response too redirect the user. You would like to create an answer so i can accepted it or else i will create one with working code to help others have same problem.

Comment: go ahead and write an answer yourself. you did most of the work ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Jakumi comments i manage to run a listener before the default [LogoutListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.php). First i have to register in services.yaml a listener with priority above 7

```
App\EventListener\BeforeLogoutListener:
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 8 }
```

Here i can't use appHelper or Security to get the current user because this listener runs BEFORE the Security/Http/Firewall. So i stop the event propagation setting new response, redirect the user too a custom logout router and THEN do my validation logic in the user.

```
public function onkernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $requestEvent)
{
    //Get data from Database and validate this action

    if ($requestEvent->getRequest()->getPathInfo() === '/logout' &&  $isExternalLogout) {
            $requestEvent->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('external_logout')));
    }

}
```

I hope I saved days from someone who was struggling to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

After Symfony **4.4** replace `GetResponseEvent`  by `RequestEvent`